# Maintain session over 3g and wifi

Tags: android, session, networking, 3g, android-wifi

I want to maintain session in my app when there is loss of WIFI connection and android switches to 3G automatically and also when the device is working on 3G and there is WIFI network availablity so the device would use WIFI.
In this changeover of connection i want to preserve the session.
How can I do it...